# Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied - Carrierwave

Tags: amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I am using the carrierwave-aws gem to handle user avatars. I have created an s3 account and bucket and created an IAM user. I granted the IAM user AmazonS3FullAccess policy. I also copied the same policy to the s3 bucket (making it public). My keys are stored in my enviornemnt and I have triple-checked that they are correct. Below is my configuration:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 config.storage    = :aws
 config.aws_bucket = ENV["AWS_BUCKET"]
 config.aws_acl    = 'public-read'

 config.aws_credentials = {
  access_key_id:     ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY"],
  secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_KEY"],
  region:            'us-east-1',
  stub_responses:    Rails.env.test? 
 }
end
```

With that, I am receiving the following error: Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied when trying to upload a user avatar. Any thoughts on what I could be missing? I've spent hours trying many different things and I'm stumped!

Comment: Check for CORS origin config in s3 bucket setting

Comment: My CORS config allows all origins and get, post and put methods

Comment: and policy also set ?

Comment: that have rights you access s3 bucket ROLE of user ?

Comment: Yes policy is set. I got it to work by unchecking all the options under "public access settings". I feel that there should be a better solution, however.

Comment: ohh okay so working now ?

Comment: yes it's working after the public access settings were changed. Looking into a better/more secure solution however.

Comment: oh that's nice it is working but for to find problem many can be VPC endpoint , if you are using VM time and date problem so hard to find thn what is reason behind error. Using RUBY ?